# IntelliJ IDEA в корне проекта не отображаются пакеты

Tags: intellij-idea

Совсем не отображаются пакеты в дереве. Только файлы, которые вне пакетов. Произошло это после активной работы с гитом и внезапной перезагрузки компьютера.
Может кто-то знает, как это лечится? И копировала папку, и перезагружала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создай новый проект. скопируй папку `src` в новый проект.

Comment: Попробуйте File->Open выберите pom.xml и нажмите ОК

Answer (score 1):

Помогли найти ответ.
Правой кнопкой по pom.xml -> Add as maven project

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся в WebStorm с аналогичным. Решил следующим образом:
File -> Repair IDE... и далее справа снизу на всплывающем экране появляются шаги IDE Repair, нпр., первый шаг:

- 'Refresh Indexable Files' recovery step (1 of 6) was performed
  и доступны две кнопки - "Everythings Works Now" и "Rescan Project Indexes"

Нажал на "Rescan Project Indexes" и IDE Repair перешла на шаг 2:

- 'Refresh Indexable Files' recovery step (2 of 6) was performed
  и где уже доступны следующие кнопки - "Everythings Works Now" и "Reopen Project"

После нажатия на "Reopen Project" структуру проекта обновилась и всё ок и я нажал на  "Everythings Works Now". Возможно кому-то следует пройти все шаги.

Надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно удалить папку. idea и 
 в меню: Создать новый проект из имеющихся файлов –> Проект Maven

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с совершенно такой же проблемой *(только IDEA не видела проект при самом первом открытии)*. Решилось выбором опции `Maven - Reload project` на файле `pom.xml`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]